# Setting selected item on Listbox in Silverlight - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a databound Listbox bound to a generic list as follows (Provider is a very simple class that just includes a single property (Name).

```
ProviderList = new List<Provider>();
//Populate list
Providers.ItemsSource = ProviderList;
```

I can save the selected item with no problem but I can't manage to set the selected item from code afterwards. I am trying to do so as follows:

```
int x = Providers.Items.IndexOf((Provider)_Settings["provider"]);
```

However `IndexOf()` is always returning -1. If I inspect both Providers.Items[1] and _Setting["provider"] at runtime using the immediate window they both return

```
{StoreRetrieveData.Provider}
Name: "Greenflag"
```

Am I doing something wrong (well clearly I am)?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you are comparing two different objects with same value? Can you try the following code instead:

```
Provider provider = (Provider)_Settings["provider"];
items.OfType<Provider>().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(provider.Name));
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with LINQ syntax and can't get this working. I'm using your code as "var test = Providers.Items.OfType<Provider>().Where(p => p.Name.Equals(provider.Name));"

Comment: Recieving this error when inspecting "System.collections...<TSource>.Current" - 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StoreRetrieveData.Provider>' does not contain a definition for 'System' and no extension method 'System' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<StoreRetrieveData.Provider>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you are using .Net 3.5 or above, make sure you have `using System.Linq` at the top of your code file. If you don't want to use LINQ, you will have to use a loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ListBox.Items
    .OfType<ColumnDescriptor>()
    .FirstOrDefault(c =>
        String.Equals(
            c.Name,
            ((Provider)_Settings["provider"]).Name,
            StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to overload Equals and the == operator of your Provider class for this to work. Otherwise your comparison will fail if the objects are different instances. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx